# J#/C# Update/Refresh GUI Thread

Tags: c#, progress-bar, refresh, repaint, j#

I have a function that simply fills a progress bar.

```
private void FillProgressBar(ProgressBar bar, Color c, int percent)
{
    int steps = 10;
    bar.set_Value(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < percent / steps; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        bar.set_Value((i+1)*10) + bar.get_Value());
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I summon it from the gui thread (not multi threading) and it's purpose is to slowly fill the bar.

But it doesn't seem to be doing it, although the value does raise.

Any suggestions on how to update a specific control or the whole form?
PS : as you can see, this.Refresh() didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

After updating the progress bar.

more on `DoEvents` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code don't let the main message loop execute and so it'll block all messages including `WM_PAINT` ones...

You shouldn't do that, use a thread, use a timer : don't block the UI.

And don't use `Application.DoEvents` it's bad programming practice and shouldn't even exists.